# how to enable errors when uploading to bigquery using nodejs gcloud

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, gcloud

using the bigquery UI I have an option to enable mistakes by checking the

```
Number of errors allowed
```

now when I am using the Gcloud in nodejs how can I enable errors?

```
fs.writeFile("/tmp/bq_json_file_new.json", myJSON, function(err){});
fs.createReadStream("/tmp/bq_json_file_new.json")
  .pipe(table.createWriteStream(metadata))
  .on('complete', function(job) {
    job
      .on('error', console.log)
      .on('complete', function(metadata) {
        console.log('job completed', metadata);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [`maxBadRecords`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.maxBadRecords) field in the job configuration.  You can specify this when inserting a job in the BigQuery API.  I'm not sure how the nodejs client looks, but if you're passing in a job-shaped object, you should be able to specify `maxBadRecords` in its load job configuration.

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer using [Danny Kitt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4001094/danny-kitt)  answer:

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud')({
  keyFilename: '../config/keyfile.json',
  projectId: 'my-project'
});

var request = require('request');

var bigquery = gcloud.bigquery();


var dataset = bigquery.dataset('my_dataset');
var table = dataset.table('my_table');

var metadata = {
    sourceFormat: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    maxBadRecords: 2
};

fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('./myFile.json')
  .pipe(table.createWriteStream(metadata))
  .on('complete', function(job) {
   job
      .on('error', console.log)
      .on('complete', function(metadata) {
        console.log('job completed', metadata);
      });
  });
```